# Serializing Vs Parsing in EF SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parsing, serialization

I have a very big doubt about this ways to do one persistence storage of struct efficiency:

Option 1:

```
public class Entity1{
    private String _bunchOfIntegers;

    public Bunch BunchOfIntegers
    {
        get
        {
            return ParseToIntegers(_bunchOfIntegers);
        }
        set
        {
            _bunchOfIntegers = ArrayToString<int>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public class Entity1{
    private byte[] _bunchOfIntegers;

    public Bunch BunchOfIntegers
    {
        get
        {
            return Deserialize(_bunchOfIntegers);
        }
        set
        {
            _bunchOfIntegers = Serialize(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Bunch Struct

```
public struct Bunch{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
     ....
}
```

Which option is better for use and store in SQL with entity framework? More performance? Less size?

Comment: Have you actually tried to make it workd with EF ? Also why a custom serialization and not a complex type ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806159/what-is-a-complex-type-in-entity-framework-and-when-to-use-it

Comment: @Guillaume It could be possible use Flags instead of integers with complex types (i have other structs with this "inconvenience"). I go to take a look at complex type while.

Comment: a string would most likely be the smallest (depending on the datatype). However, since the datatypes are ints (4 bytes) and the string equivalent to the highest number has 10 characters (10 bytes minimum), I think the smallest and also most efficient way would be a flat one-to-many relationship (or even many-to-many, depending on frequency)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Like a complex type? I'm talking about 14 integers minimum (low values, maybe not greater than short) but the software gonna have a lot (a lot, seriously) 'entity1's.

Comment: not really. Just save that as a List of Integers, EF should make a one-to-many relationship to a two-column-table. If you have many multiple values, a many-to-many relationship might be adequate to decode the integers into their ID's. In any case, you'll end up with less space needed and most likely also a better performance, since both values can be indexed (not to mention query possibilities)

Comment: Mmm, i'm gonna make small test with all the options, thanks, @DevilSuichiro I didn't know EF manages Enumerable types (I know use public virtual Collection for 1-M, M-M but didn't know that kind of use). Thanks. I will write with the times and performance for future people when i can.