# Double column with code first EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Doing code first try with EF in C# and I got stuck because I declared

```
public class Members
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "someDisplayName")]
    public bool ABool{ get; set; }


    public ReferenceClass ReferenceClass { get; set; }
    public byte ReferenceClassId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity framework adding migration after creating this i got

ID

NAME

SURNAME

ABool
ReferenceClassID

ReferenceClass_ID

in my SQL database. Now nothings maps correctly. How to fix it?!

Comment: I suppose that the Id property of the ReferenceClass is an int and not a byte?

Comment: can you please add the actual migration and if available the expected table definition ? also can you clarify what SQL you are connection to (ms-sql, mysql,...)?

Comment: I will try it with an Int. and I'm working with MS SQL. I saw few examples where they showed this way and the got only ReferenceClassID not ReferenceClass_ID

Comment: i would like to see those examples. also not sure you even need to define ReferenceClassId (though you should) i believe if you omit it gets setup for you anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is unclear to entity framework.

If I look at the names of your identifiers, it seems that you want to model a one-to-many relationship between `ReferenceClasses` and `Members`: every `ReferenceClass has zero or more`Members`, every`Member`belongs to exactly one`ReferenceClass`.

This is not how you designed your model.You told entity framework that Members is a composition of the complex type `ReferenceClass` and a byte property ReferenceClassId.

See:

- [Stack Overflow: Entity Framework Complex Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806159/what-is-a-complex-type-in-entity-framework-and-when-to-use-it)
- [Entity Framework: model various types of relations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx) (a.o. one-to-many)

If you look at the column names that entity framework modelled for you, it is clear that it sees `ReferenceClass` as a complex type (used for composition)

If you want one-to-many you'll have to add the proper navigation properties. You were half way, except for the byte foreign key.

```
class Member
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Navigation properties:
    // a member belongs to exactly one ReferenceClass via foreign key
    public int ReferenceClassId {get; set;}
    public ReferenceClass ReferenceClass {get; set;}
}
class ReferenceClass {get; set;}
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
    // Navigation Properties:
    // A reference class has zero or more Members:
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members {get; set;}
}
```

If you follow the [code-first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), then this is enough for entity framework to recognize the one-to-many. Don't forget the **virtual** near the ICollection!

If you want special column names or table names, you could use Attributes to name them. Although I prefer fluent API, because that would allow you to use the same classes in different databases with different tables.

One-to-many in fluent api: in your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // a ReferenceClass has zero or more Members
    // every member belongs to exactly one ReferenceClass
    // via foreign key ReferenceClassId
    modelBuilder.Entity<ReferenceClass>()
        .HasMany(refClass => refClass.Members)
        .WithRequired(member => member.ReferenceClass)
        .HasforeignKey(member => member.ReferenceClassId)
```

You can use this if you have different names in your properties. You could also use ToTable and HasColumName if you want to specify different names

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ReferenceClass>()
    .ToTable("MyTable")
    .Property(refClass => refClass.Name)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnName("MyColumnName")
    .HasMaxLength(40);
```

[A very good tutorial for entity framework code first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

as @BobMeijwaard pointed out it is likely that you want your class definition to be

```
public class Members
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "someDisplayName")]
    public bool ABool{ get; set; }


    public ReferenceClass ReferenceClass { get; set; }
    public int ReferenceClassId { get; set; }
}
```

changing `public byte ReferenceClassId { get; set; }` to `public int ReferenceClassId { get; set; }`

if more information can be provided i can update my answer if this is not correct

Comment: This worked, it solved all the problems I had. now I just need to drop the extra column?

Comment: well i think you can do that manually being that its a local dev and would not get generated in the future. if in the end this did solve your problem you should mark an answer. it will help you get more answers for future questions as people do not like to answer others with a lot of 'open' questions